# Implicit cast operator not compiling outside original assembly

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.2

I'm having trouble with an implicit cast operator that's working fine inside the assembly where the type is declared, but doesn't when used from external programs/libraries referencing that original assembly.

Suppose I have this struct:

```
public readonly struct Tensor
{
    public readonly IntPtr Ptr;

    // Other stuff here..

    public static unsafe implicit operator float*(in Tensor tensor) => (float*)tensor.Ptr.ToPointer();
}
```

This works perfectly fine when used from the same assembly, ie. I can do:

```
// Say t is a Tensor
float* p = t;
```

But if I try to do the same from another program/anything referencing the assembly `Tensor` is defined, the compiler fails saying:

> error CS0029: Couldn't implicitly convert the type 'Tensor' into 'float*'

The weird thing is that Visual Studio isn't showing any kind of error in the IDE itself, everything looks fine there:

[image]

Also, I'm not getting any error whatsoever about this in the errors list tab, I can only see those error messages by looking at the compiler output console.

This doesn't seem right:

- Why is this working fine in the original assembly?
- Why am I not getting any kind of visual error indication from VS in that code, given the fact that it isn't compiling?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: this is the repo link, if it helps: https://github.com/Sergio0694/NeuralNetwork.NET

The `Tensor` struct is in the NeuralNetwork.NET project, under APIs\Structs. You can try that with any of the other projects, the implicit cast is always failing for me.

**EDIT #2**: I've opened an issue, here's the link: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23945

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution, recompile it and if still fails to restart VS?

Comment: @Gusman Yup, tried that, also tried on two different computers and on different projects, same result. I've edited the question and added the repo link, you can try that on your PC if you feel like it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `Allow unsafe code` checked in build properties of the other assembly? If not, I'd try that first.

Comment: Seems something to do with new "in" modifier, because if remove it - compiles fine. Maybe a bug even, with all those fast new changes to language bugs appear far more often than before.

Comment: @Evk That's weird, I have C# 7.2 set to all the projects in the solution. Plus, removing that `in` modifier would not be the ideal solution, as it'd end up copying all the struct value every time. You might be right, it could be a bug with the compiler, and given that the `ref struct` modifier is bugged too, it wouldn't surprise me. I'll try reporting that, thanks!

Comment: Sure, I don't suggest to remove it (if only temporary until you find the real reason, or if that is a bug it is fixed). You can try to report it here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues, but note there are 4000 open issues there, so don't expect very fast reply and fix :)

Comment: @Evk Woah, never seen any repo with that many open issues before ahahah I'll try to report it there as well as sending a feedback message through VS, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: We'll prioritize this for 15.6 or 15.7. Thanks for reporting the bug.